# How to implement ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback

Tags: ios

i am currently trying to implement an addressbook feature for my app.

I need a method to update my core data when user edits/add/delete contacts.

I read about ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback function that could help register a callback, however I do not know how to implement this. For example: http://www.iappnow.com/2011/08/21/abaddressbookregisterexternalchangecallback-works-but-data-is-stale/

Im still new to objective c programming,
can anyone provide a link or sample on how to implement it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just found it! `<http://ldt.stanford.edu/~educ39109/yaac/lab3/iphone/Classes/Contacts.m>` Use @protocol to register a delegate method, then add the method to the viewcontroller